# GET id from php with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, get

Morning! I'm having problems with my code. I need to click an image and get an overlay with the information of that image. I have the overlay and my image sends the ID.

My php is:

```
echo "<td><a href='#?id=".$row['id']."'' class='qwe'><img src='../covers/nocover.jpg' width='100' /></a></td>";
```

And my JavaScript is:

```
$( ".qwe" ).click(function() {
  $.get("Get.php", function(respuesta){
      $("#popup").html(respuesta);
  })
  $( "#popup" ).show("fade");
});
```

my Get.php is:

```
<h1>You sent a value by GET: <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?></h1>
```

when i click my anchor class .qwe my overlay works good, it opens and show me the Get.php file inside but the problem is that i don't know how to catch the id that my anchor is sending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the element with an id

```
<a id='".$row['id']."' href='#?id=".$row['id']."'' class='qwe'
```

Read the id with `this.id` and you can send it up

```
$( ".qwe" ).click(function() {
   var id = this.id;
   $.get("Get.php", { "id" : id }, function(respuesta){
```

if you really want to not set the id of the element, you can read the attr("href") and append it to the url.

```
$( ".qwe" ).click(function() {
   var qs = $(this).attr("href")
   $.get("Get.php" + qs, function(respuesta){
```

Comment: I took your answer and I did this:<a id='?id=".$row['id']."' href='#' class='qwe'... And works!! thank you bro!

Comment: id can't start with number in HTML4, something to keep in mind; perhaps `data-id` attribute would be a better pick.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `id` attribute on the `a` element it will be accessible with JS

```
echo "<td><a id='". $row['id'] ."' href='#?id=".$row['id']."'' class='qwe'><img src='../covers/nocover.jpg'     width='100' /></a></td>";
```

And then in the JS:

```
$( ".qwe" ).click(function() {
    var id = this.id;
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the `id` attribute (as Jack mentioned, you can't have an `id` attribute's value beginning with a number in HTML4) you could use HTML5's `data-` attributes and access these with jQuery's `.data()` function.